# Change Python Version from 3.6 to 2.7 in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently set up a new application in Elastic Beanstalk and created an environment using python. I want to use this environment to host a small Django web app I made using python 2.7 and Django 1.11. However, when I set up the environment, it defaulted to python 3.6 and for some reason the option to change the configuration is disabled.

Does anyone know why it is disabled and how I can change this configuration?

[disabled configuration button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH3fU.png)

Comment: EB will not change from Python 2 <-> 3. This is considered a platform update. You cannot perform a platform update between configurations.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.platform.upgrade.html

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I went ahead and made a whole new environment with the correct version of Python.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the AWS CLI (or the EBCLI) to [update your environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html) with the platform of choice:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
  --environment-name ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
  --solution-stack-name PYTHON_2_7_SOLUTION_STACK \
  --region REGION_NAME
```

where,

**PYTHON_2_7_SOLUTION_STACK** --> the solution stack you'd like to use. Find the latest one in the [Python 2.7 series here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.python).

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed. I was just able to downgrade from Python 3.6 to 3.4.

First, list the available solution stacks:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks
```

Then, update your environment (below is an example of downgrading to 2.7):

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
--environment-name 'your-env-name-here' \
--solution-stack-name '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.6 running Python 2.7'
```

Comment: it says unknown option to the stack name

Comment: @SizzlingCode: aws changes the available stacks over time. Make sure the arg you supply for solution-stack-name is among those returned for the first command: `aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks` at